# How to extract ranges of contiguous Ints efficiently/elegantly?

Tags: scala, range, seq

Let's start with a sequence of integer like:

```
val seq = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10,11,14,15,16,18)
```

I want to get a sequence of pairs representing contiguous sets, such as:

```
val ranges = List(1,6,9,11,14,16,18,18)
```

Alternative format `Seq[(Int,Int)]` is acceptable as well:

```
val ranges = List((1,6),(9,11),(14,16),(18,18))
```

Explanation:
 - integers in range `1..6` and `11..16` are in `seq`
 - integer `18` is in `seq`, but has no successors or predecessors, so it appears as `18,18` in `ranges`

Note that single-element sequences should be always reported as pairs, such as in :

```
val seq = List(18, 19, 21)
```

Which should give as result:

```
val ranges = List(18,19,21,21)
```

Or, if you prefer *Tuple2 style*:

```
val ranges = List((18,19),(21,21))
```

I would like to have a function to derive `ranges` from `seq`; a solution (provided by a colleague) is:

```
def toRanges(a: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
  val min = a.map(x => (x, a contains x - 1)).filter(!_._2).map(_._1)
  val max = a.map(x => (x, a contains x + 1)).filter(!_._2).map(_._1)
  return (min ++ max).sorted
}
```

Which is elegant, indeed, but I'm not sure about efficiency, due to use of `contains`.

Can anyone provide an even better solution in terms of efficiency or elegance?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that, for efficiency sake, `a contains` might be substituted with a `contains` on a `toSet` version of the same `Seq` `a` ; this may improve performance on large `Seq`s, whilst not changing dramatically this code.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be ordered?

Comment: @TravisBrown In my case yes, but we could always resort to applying a sorted method to Seq a before searching for ranges. Thus, I would say that sorted elements is a reasonable starting condition in any case.

Comment: I have clarified expected format and fixed an error in result (int ranges `(9,11)` and `(14,16)` were mangled into ... something strange :) ). @TravisBrown

Comment: Both solutions from @Dima and Travis Brown seem quite elegant to me: thank you guys! I will do some performance testing on the solutions to clarify which is better in that respect, while I can imagine that Dima's solution might have an edge since it should generate less intermediate objects, thus removing some burden from GC for very large integer lists. Note that this solution shoud work in a huge data analysis system Spark-based, where millions (or billions...) of such lists (each having ten to hundreds thousands points) have to be analyzed simultaneously, so efficiency is also important.

Answer (score 3):

If the input is ordered (or you're willing to sort it first), you can do this pretty concisely in a single pass with `foldLeft` (well, two passes with the `reverse`, but that's an artifact of working with lists and could be avoided if you're willing to give up some elegance):

```
seq.foldLeft[List[(Int, Int)]](Nil) {
  case ((a, b) :: rest, i) if i == b + 1 => (a, i) :: rest
  case (acc, i) => (i, i) :: acc
}.reverse
```

Which in this case gives us the following:

```
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,6), (9,11), (14,16), (18,18))
```

For each element we check whether it's the successor of the end of the last range we added. If it is, we replace the end in that range. If it's not, we start a new range.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps:

```
(None +: seq.toStream.map(x => Some(x)) :+ None).sliding(2).flatMap {
    case Seq(None, Some(b)) => List(b)
    case Seq(Some(a), None) => List(a)
    case Seq(Some(a), Some(b)) if b - a == 1 => Nil
    case Seq(Some(a), Some(b)) => List(a,b)
}.toList
```

Comment: Dima, there's a little bug in the code: if you have `val seq = List(18,19,21)`,  result is `List(18,19,21)`, which is not good (it should be `List(18,19,21,21)` instead, since element count should be always even).
I think that this happens since list used by `flatMap` is, in this case: `List(List(18), List(18, 19), List(19, 21))`, so after copying `List(19,21)` in intermediate list (pre-flat-mapping), there's no `21` (or `List(21)`) to be copied through. What do you think?

Comment: @logtwo yeah, you are right. It did not handle the last element correctly. Fixed it now. Prepending a dummy element to the head wasn't enough (needed the same trick at the end), so I mapped it to Options instead, that way we can use `None` as a sentinel. Note converting it to a stream in the middle - that avoids an extra traversal so that everything can be done in one go.